# pip error while installing mayavi

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install

I run this code   sudo pip install mayavi
I installed vtk by using brew and it works with python up to this point everything is fine. But pip,easy_install and also installing from source code gives error at the same point. error indicates setup.py line 178.

```
print "Generating the mlab reference documentation"
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are using Python 2 and not Python 3? The later requires parenthesis for print.

Comment: I also tought like you I use python 2 versions and python 3 but they use pip2.7 pip3.4 syntax pip it self points to python2.7

Comment: I think you are right agold because when I run which pip it points to    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip

Comment: I think problem was as agold said but I am facing an other problem with pip I will create a new topic thank you